# Is there a python function in QGIS to detect if the output file is saved to the hard disk?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm currently using QGIS 2.4 and writing some custom scripts on it. A proper script not only accomplishes its function, but also accepts user defined parameters and checks for possibilities of errors.

So far I couldn't find any information related to a built-in QGIS function or library that checks for error possibilities in the output (e.g. output file exists, no space on output disk, no writing permissions).

Currently I only need one function, to check if the output file is created or not. Is there any QGIS function to accomplish this task or should I rely on python's `os` library? It would be great if QGIS do has this functionality not only for an easy check, but also to parse the exact reason of the error.

I'm currently using `processing.core.VectorWriter` to save the output files.

Comment: Just use os.path.exists(path) method?

Comment: `os.path.exists(path)` will be the solution if there isn't a built-in function in QGIS. However, I would like to see the exact error type, why the saving has failed (e.g. driver error, geometry error, physical error) in an error object.

Comment: I think that will popup anyway, during the file saving phase, OGR/GDAL should throw an error. Try saving in an invalid way to confirm this.

Comment: I tried to execute my script on an invalid shapefile, and yes, it resulted in an error. However, it sent my custom error message from the `try` - `except` section of my code. In the log it said, it couldn't load the following models and scripts: notinorder, watersheds, etc. I hoped for a wrapper function that returns an error type based on these information.